# How can I use tlsConfig with RoundTripper?

Tags: go

I have this code that implements an http client with a custom RoundTripper to add few header by default whenever `Client` is used to make http calls.

```
var Client *http.Client

type customTransport struct {
    underlyingTransport http.RoundTripper
}

func (t *customTransport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer")
    req.Header.Add("Version", "2017-11-23") 
    return t.underlyingTransport.RoundTrip(req)
}

func CreateClient() error {
    // Setup HTTPS client
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    }
    tlsConfig.BuildNameToCertificate()

    // transport := &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig}
    // Client = &http.Client{Transport: transport}
    Client = &http.Client{Transport: &customTransport{underlyingTransport: http.DefaultTransport}}

    return nil
}
```

You can see that I have a `tlsConfig`.
My question is how do I incorporate this `tlsConfig` into my Client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You handle this by calling the original/default transport in your `RoundTrip` method, which you're already doing:

```
return t.underlyingTransport.RoundTrip(req)
```

So you just have to configure it properly:

```
Client = &http.Client{Transport: &customTransport{underlyingTransport: http.DefaultTransport}}
```

Which you're also already doing.

The only thing you need to change is that you should use a transport using your TLS config, rather than `http.DefaultTransport`:

```
transport := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig,
}
Client = &http.Client{Transport: &customTransport{underlyingTransport: transport}}
```